# How do I validate field-yield is populated before moving onto the next step in a multi-stage form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

My apologies, I am certain this is a simple solution. However, the community has been so kind in the past, so I thought I would see if someone could point me in the right direction.

We utilise an external piece of software for managing our database and hosting our data capture forms. This solution limits us to calling field yields when we build our forms.

So my HTML for a multi step form may look something like this:

```
<form id="form-1">                                          

<fieldset id="step1">
    <h3> Are you Male or Female?</h3>

<field-yield data-field="F_901_ONLINE_GENDER"></field-yield>
</fieldset>


<fieldset id="step2"  style="display:none">
    <h3 style="font-family:poppins;"> Please tell us about you?</h3>

<field-yield data-field="F_3_FIRSTNAME"></field-yield>
<field-yield data-field="F_4_LASTNAME"></field-yield>                           
</fieldset> 


<fieldset id="step3"  style="display:none;">
    <h3> Please find your Address</h3>

        <div data-option="UK_ADDRESS_LOOKUP">
            <label data-db-localized-content="UK_ADDRESS_LOOKUP_LABEL"></label>
            <div class="input">
                <input class="PCODE" name="UK_ADDRESS_LOOKUP_POSTCODE" type="text" placeholder="" data-db-localized-placeholder="UK_ADDRESS_LOOKUP_PLACEHOLDER" value=""required><br>
                <button class="mbbutton" type="button" data-db-localized-content="UK_ADDRESS_LOOKUP_LOOKUP_BUTTON"></button> <br>

                <select class="form-control" name="UK_ADDRESS_LOOKUP_ADDRESS" type="text" placeholder="" required>
                    <option is-placeholder data-db-localized-content="UK_ADDRESS_LOOKUP_ADDRESS_PLACEHOLDER"></option>
                </select>
            </div> <br><br>
        </div><field-yield data-field="F_9_TOWNCITY"></field-yield><field-yield data-field="F_6_ADDRESS1"></field-yield><field-yield data-field="F_11_POSTCODE"></field-yield>
<input type="submit"style="display:none;" data-db-localized-value="FORM_SUBMIT">
</fieldset>


<div class="col-12">
<br>
<button type="button" id="next">Start Quote!</button>
<p style="height: 40px;text-align:left;padding-left: 10px;padding-bottom: 0px;margin-bottom: -25px;"><button class="customBackBtn previous shadow" style="display:none;font-size:15px!important" id="previous" type="button"> <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-left"></i> <strong>Back</strong></button></p><br>

</form>
```

The system has inbuilt checks that make the field yields "required" However, it would appear that these only operate on the "submit button" so if a user skips through to the end, missing a filed on step1 the form does not submit, it also doesn't display the error message coded into the field yields.

As you can imagine, this is rubbish UX and so we lose a lot of form completions.

What I am looking to achieve is code that validates that all fields in each step are populated before moving to the next step, preventing users from getting to a submit button that won't function.

current JS is:

```
$(function () {

    var currentPage = 1;
    var maxPage = 3; //if additional fieldset steps add the max page here i.e., if 7 pages maxPage = 7

    $("#next").click(function () {
        if (currentPage < maxPage) {
            var nextPage = currentPage + 1;
        } else {
            return; //if already at max page 
        }


        trackProgress(100 * ((nextPage - 1) / maxPage).toFixed(1) + '%'); //get rid of decimal points (make a whole number)
        $("#step" + currentPage).hide();
        $("#step" + nextPage).show();
        $("#previous").show();


        currentPage = nextPage;
        if (currentPage === maxPage) {
            $('#next').hide()
            $('input[type="submit"]').delay(2000).show(0);
            $('#thanks').delay(2000).show(0);

            // Show submit button & thank you paragraph
        }
    });

    $("#previous").click(function () {
        if (currentPage !== 1) {
             $('#spinner').removeClass('hidden')
            var prevPage = currentPage - 1;
        } else {
            return;
        }

        trackProgress(100 * ((prevPage - 1) / maxPage).toFixed(1) + '%');
        $("#step" + currentPage).hide();
        $("#step" + prevPage).show();
        $('input[type="submit"]').hide();
        $('#thanks').hide();
        $("#next").show();

        currentPage = prevPage;
        if (currentPage === 1) {
            $('#previous').hide()
        }
    })

});
```

This allows both a progress bar to work, a back button for traversing the form and show/hide for each step.
I wanted to add something like the following to the following to validate field completion.

```
if ($('input[name="F_901_ONLINE_GENDER"]').val() == '' && $('input[name="F_3_FIRSTNAME"]').val() == '' && $('input[name="F_4_LASTNAME"]').val() == ''){
                        alert('Please complete all questions');
```

However this is not working and I am at a loss as to what to try next.

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Comment: As I understand something replaces `<field-yield data-field="F_3_FIRSTNAME"></field-yield>` with input field after you submit your code right? Do you have some kind of event after this replacement has happened?

Comment: Yes the `<field-yield>` is called from the system and populates as per a field template. So we design in the system the following field template for `F_3_FIRSTNAME`: `<div>
<input
    class="form-control"
    type="text" 
    id="{{name}}" 
    name="{{name}}" 
    placeholder=""     value=""
/>
 <div class="form-field">
{{{field}}}
    </div>
    <div class="error-message">
        
    </div>
    </div>` This then populates with settings defined in the system - this includes relevant text for validation fails - which may be why some JS conflicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your system replaces `<field-yield>` tags, but I guess there will be typical form fields. So you need to write some general validation function, which will validate all fields in step and allow users to move on the next step if validation passed.

Function to validate all input fields in step:

```
function validateStep(step) {
    var stepWrapper = $('fieldset#step'+step);
    var emptyFields = 0;

    $('input[type="text"], select, textarea', stepWrapper).each(function(i, el) {
        if ($(el).val() == '') {
            emptyFields++;
            return false;
        }
    });

    //check radio buttons
    var radioGroups = {};
    //group radio buttons by name
    $(':radio', stepWrapper).each(function() {
        radioGroups[this.name] = true;
    });

    //count "checked" radio buttons in groups
    for (var radioName in radioGroups) {
        var checked = !!$(':radio[name="'+radioName+'"]:checked', stepWrapper).length;
        if (!checked) {
            emptyFields++;
        }
    }

    return emptyFields;
}
```

now you have step validation, the only thing you need to is call this function before step change:

```
$("#next").click(function () {

    //validate before move
    if (validateStep(currentPage)) {
        alert("Please fill all fields before move to next step!");
        return false;
    }


    if (currentPage < maxPage) {
        var nextPage = currentPage + 1;
    } else {
        return; //if already at max page 
    }

    //... rest of your code
}
```

Hope this helps you.

---

**UPDATE:**
Here is a working example of your page form: https://codepen.io/zur4ik/pen/LYYqjgM
I had a mistake in each loop.

Comment: Hi @zur4ik Thank you for the response! So I have tested this and unfortunately it didn't work, my assumption is that this is conflicting with code from the system itself. `<field-yield>` calls from the system not only the field information but the field format. Within this, each field looks to validate the information with the class `required` I have a test example running here:  (https://energy.switchyourprovider.co.uk/jQtest/form.html)

Comment: It doesn't display the error fields, it also prevents moving forward even if the field is populated. I think this is because the other steps are returning unpopulated?

Comment: `var stepWrapper = $('fieldset#step'+step);` this must isolate only current page for validation. I'll re-check code according to your live example and write you back.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the assistance! :)

Comment: I had a mistake in breaking `each` loop. Also, I have added a live working example. You can check. The only thing you need is to handle errors on your way and expand selector for more input type fields, like radio buttons or checkboxes.

Comment: This is incredible, thank you for looking at this! You are correct, I have implemented the code on the link I pasted and it works on page one, however as the rest are radio buttons, I needed to change the code to pick this up. I assumed this was the line I would need to expand to add other field types: `$('input, select, textarea', stepWrapper).each(function(i, el) {` However I have tried both addition and replication and neither provide the desired result... I am clearly in way over my head here!!

Comment: With your new code, you can actually see on the link I posted above, how if you get to the end of the form, with missing fields, that is where the systems validation tool displays the errors. My initial attempt was to get it to run this at the end of each step.

Comment: You need to take control of radio buttons a bit different way, then text input fields. I've updated `validateStep` function here and on Codepen too. You can check how to validate radio buttons.

Comment: Awesome, Thank you so much! I really appreciate you taking the time to walk me through it! Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202668/discussion-between-mb18-and-zur4ik).